# How to use Phonegap properly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, ant

I have worked a lot to install Phonegap in my computer with Android. Now I have the Android SDK and everything is fine. But I have looked for a way to check my app in Android and apparently I don't need the Android SDK. I have seen, that you just have to use the webpage of phonegap build. So now I ask me, "why did I install Android SDK, Eclipse, JDK, Ant, and all that stuff?

I would like to know what's better, use the phonegap build webpage or use the Android SDK with Eclipse, which emulator by the way, is very very slow. I cannot work with it.

And in addition, I would like to know how to check my updates in the Android App with the SDK. I mean, if I use the Phonegap phone app it updates in real time, but I would like to know how to check it manually with Eclipse, because I suppose that I got to build it or something like that.

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you use Phonegap build to compile and generate your APK, you will need some IDE or TextEditor to code i.e to write your js and css files. So using an IDE such as Eclipse or text editor such as SublimeText is recommended. Plus in case of phonegap you might come across situations when you will need to access device api's and for that you would have to use plugins. Plugins are coded in Java i.e for android framework, so using it in Eclipse along with Android SDK is needed to edit code in proper way, as android coding is best with SDK support on eclipse or studio. Also for accessing third party api's such as PayPal, you will need to add their phonegap sdk to your code and plugins too. So using IDE is helpful and necessary. Also by using eclipse, you can edit your Manifest and other resources to be used by your application, and access features such as code suggestions and error debugging if any. Both are not available in phonegap build.

Incase of emulator being slow, use Genymotion emulator. It is many many many times faster than emulator with sdk and has more options and features. It can be linked to SDK i.e eclipse via a plugin.

Hope this helps and clears your doubts :)